# how to dynamically call instance methods in typescript?

Tags: typescript, methods, dynamic-programming, dispatch

I have an object and I want to dynamically call a method on it.

Having typechecking would be nice but that maybe impossible. 
But I can't even get it to compile at all currently:

```
  const key: string = 'someMethod'
  const func = this[key]
  func(msgIn)
```

gives me this error...

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type 
because expression of type 'any' can't be used 
to index type 'TixBot'.
```

I tried some other type options without success.

```
  const key: any = cmd.func
  const func: any = this[key]
```

Apart from `@ts-ignore` how could I solve this?
I was wondering if I can use `.call()` or `bind` to somehow work around it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Typescript will error if it can't check that the string used is a valid member of the class. This for example will work:

```
class MyClass {
    methodA() {
        console.log("A")
    }
    methodB() {
        console.log("B")
    }

    runOne() {
        const random = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "methodA" : "methodB" // random is typed as "methodA" | "methodB"
        this[random](); //ok, since random is always a key of this
    }
}
```

In the samples above removing the explicit type annotation from a constant should give you the literal type and allow you to use the const to index into `this`.

You could also type the string as `keyof Class` :

```
class MyClass {
    methodA() {
        console.log("A")
    }
    methodB() {
        console.log("B")
    }

    runOne(member: Exclude<keyof MyClass, "runOne">) { // exclude this method
        this[member](); //ok
    }
}
```

If you already have a `string` using an assertion to `keyof MyClass` is also an option although this is not as type safe (`this[member as keyof MyClass]` where `let member: string`)

Comment: interesting so the TS compiler is doing some guesses into the code, esp if you have strings hardwired into your code. I had some real problems with exporting enums from definition files... so types I will try.

Comment: @dcsan typescript has support for string literal types. So `"A"` can be a value if used in an expression or a type when used in a type annotation.

Comment: right yes `type` works, but `enum`s don't work within types.d.ts files...