# How to call class method dynamically with variable while avoiding TypeScript error 7053?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This code runs fine, i.e. executes the method called `import_codeData` on the class `DataIimporter` by dynamically calling `this.import_codeData()` based on the content of the string variable `task`:

[image]

However, in Visual Studio Code, TypeScript shows this error:

[image]

It gets the same error if a simple string is sent:

[image]

While this code works fine, how can I get TypeScript not to display this error in the editor?

---

**ADDENDUM:**

I reproduced this error online here at [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYwNghgzlAEAiEAuECSBbADgewE5IFNdYBvYYWS2FKAawC5YolcBLAOwHMBucq2ENnbNcAVxBI8ACgCUpCvypIAFqygA6GrVgBeWACJWWPEgD6AE2QQADNYCM+3vwC+fJQWaz5ipaqgBtFTVNaFoAXVknKlcFSiMcfAsrWzsvMh9KQWFsMAJ1MGxOKQByeJMOTlhLFBTimSjKVxis5iqrDATCYj12AgB3BHbjfCJI4Gq0Ya71MsSJlLGJjpMiTQ8kSKA):

```
class DataImporter {

    task: string;

    constructor() {
        this.task = "import_data001";
    }

    test() {
        this[this.task]();
    }

    import_data001() {
        console.log('importing data001');
    }
}

const dataImporter = new DataImporter();
dataImporter.import_data001();
dataImporter.test();
```

Comment: Minimal reproducible example on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play would be helpful

Comment: here you go: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYwNghgzlAEAiEAuECSBbADgewE5IFNdYBvYYWS2FKAawC5YolcBLAOwHMBucq2ENnbNcAVxBI8ACgCUpCvypIAFqygA6GrVgBeWACJWWPEgD6AE2QQADNYCM+3vwC+fJQWaz5ipaqgBtFTVNaFoAXVknKlcFSiMcfAsrWzsvMh9KQWFsMAJ1MGxOKQByeJMOTlhLFBTimSjKVxis5iqrDATCYj12AgB3BHbjfCJI4Gq0Ya71MsSJlLGJjpMiTQ8kSKA

Answer (score 1):

[Solution on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYwNghgzlAEAiEAuECSBbADgewE5IFNdYBvYYWS2FKAawC5ZaCBPbAMwWTSz0NwDc5KrBDYAdlCS4AriCR4AFAEpSFEVSQALAJZQAdDVqwAvLABEO3vgD6AE24AGRwEZzQkQF9hmglJVqGlRikkiw7OKm1LpQANraeobQtAC6HkGwOpyKSCyYBBzhkSYlsADk7DLi8joSZapkGRoRKulB3l4+lFY4tg4ozi4BjRkhUNhgBPpg2ADmimU9fDris7D9EIP1bbDe3qASUuvcGL38UeIEAO5cKKd8RK3AG-f4RPpLfU6uTy-W-IY-EhWkA)

The type of `task` needs to be more specific than just "string", specifically `keyof DataImporter`. But when you do that, it can also refer to keys that name non-methods, so you'd need to exclude those when trying to invoke them, or as I did, check directly that they are functions.

Type of `fn`:

> const fn: "task" | "test" | "import_data001" | (() => void) | (() => void)

Type of `fn` after only considering functions:

> const fn: () => void

```js
class DataImporter {

    task: keyof DataImporter;

    constructor() {
        this.task = "import_data001";
    }

    test() {
        const fn = this[this.task];
        if (typeof fn === 'function') { // or !== 'string'
            fn();
        }
    }

    import_data001() {
        console.log('importing data001');
    }
}

const dataImporter = new DataImporter();
dataImporter.import_data001();
dataImporter.test();
```

Partial credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/56894533/823470 for helping with the first issue. I solved the second just by looking at the inferred type of `fn` and seeing that I wanted to only consider functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
test() {
        (this[this.task as keyof DataImporter] as Function)();
}
```

- We apply the **keyof** operator to ***this.task*** and thus telling the compiler that it **this.task** represents a property of the **DataImporter** class
- We're applying **Function** to **this[this.task as keyof DataImporter]** thus asserting that it's a **Function**.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this [(playground)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hwBkIDsDmwAWAeAKlCAHsCgCYDOUAhsiANoC6AfFALxR6HHLlQDeUAGxToMALigBLZADMIAJygIoAXygB%20RVHHIIAN3kAoA6EhQAWvID2SNJlzM2vA1Ci0A0pORQA1hBCXpdnpxHHd6fCJSCgAKAEpWZl1LCRIXDWi4RGE7AAVKOUoAW3h5MlwwxmZOKKgABnUoD209eVjm-TkAbgNlWl9-QJx6IxNoAGFKAQFKACMhVnMrGxEsADFLS0YjAGNpsgp1yz5nKBJLAEE445PlIxczgCErpxu708sx57fbk8KAVwEwAkYCE5zkqDI0Uo2j%20hRm8gANFAZjC4a1ji4XHJ4H85F5KFAANTI7ouH5Yv7IADKlmKmCkqGi0mQADkihBxBMprMhPEnJioPSyLRmWzivQ4qSVD0gA):

```
type GetLength<T extends any[]> = T extends { length: infer L } ? L : never

type ZeroLength<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends () => void  ? (GetLength<Parameters<T[K]>> extends 0 ? K : never): never;
}[keyof T]

type Callable = ZeroLength<Foo>

class Foo {
  doA() {

  }

  doB() {

  }

  doC() {

  }

  multipleArgs(a: number, b: number) {
    return a + b;
  }

  runSomething(fnName: Callable) {
    this[fnName]();
  }
}
```

Comment: `T[K] extends () => void  ? K : never;` is enough, it already covers params length check https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAWhBOB7AMhAdgc2ACwDwBUA+KAXigG8AoKKAbQGkoBLNKAawhEQDMp8BdAFx8G-KBAAewdABMAzlAAUASlLEAboiYyaAfiiNhaCOoQBuSgF9aHLrwGVKoSFADCAQwA2n9wCNP0GRwSKiYOLgAYoiIhI4Axj5yClGIFNRQMogAgipp6ZaONJkAQrlU+YUZiK5llQXpALYArp7ATGABWfAYcoruRk0NvggANFC+A0MIqlQ0NPAQwE3wrO5QANTjFjT1801oAMqIDYvYLBiK3GgAcu4nwh7efgEz6TQ4THK0V7cn-CrbKAFSxAA